# What is HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) (Apache)?

Tags: php, apache, https, http-headers, webserver

Can anybody tell me how to enable HSTS in Apache server.
What are the security features of enabling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HSTS is a HTTP header telling the client that a certain domain/subdomain should always be accessed by HTTPS protocol.

In your httpd.conf goes:

```
# Optionally load the headers module:
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

<VirtualHost 67.89.123.45:443>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"
</VirtualHost>
```

(Taken from [this article](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_for_Apache_NGINX_and_Lighttpd.html).)

I would suggest starting with a small max-age, so your site will work in a few moments in the case you screw up.